# how to set a class and id to a div that don't affect each other by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i made a simple chat room. i want the comment to have different parts so i use this code to set an id and class to a div

```
$('<div id="fullBox">'+inpx+'</div>').addClass('showMessage').appendTo('#mainbox');
```

i use #fullBox to say you have a div that has larger space and i use .showMessage to say to it you have smaller space to hold the text.

therefor i can use that larger space to add some element later.

style of my id and class

```
#fullBox{
width:1100px;
margin:5px;
background-color:#fff;  
}
```

and my class

```
.showMessage{
width :1000 px;
background-color:#03C;
word-wrap:break-word;
line-height :1.3 em;
font-size :24 px;
}
```

my id has larger space and i expect that my class with smaller space hold my text but my text follow my id i don't know how to solve it.

i use two different background color to see both of them if i can see both of them i get my answer.

link code :[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackson3d/qfrhjLuu/)

and i want to know how can i have auto scrollbar to automatic show new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill all the space you have to set `width:100%` as presented below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var inpx = $('.inBox').val();
    $('.inBox').val("");
    $('<div id="fullBox">' + inpx + '</div>').addClass('showMessage').appendTo('#mainbox');

  });
});
```

```css
#mainbox {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  background: url(../img/dash.png);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #06F;
  z-index: 900;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#bottombox {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  background: url(../img/dash.png);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #06F;
}
.inBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  resize: none;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: -18px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 65px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#fullBox {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.showMessage {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainbox"></div>
<div id="bottombox">
  <form>
    <textarea class="inBox"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Or even better you can remove the `width` from that elements (`fullBox` and `showMessage`) and will be inherited from parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var inpx = $('.inBox').val();
    $('.inBox').val("");
    $('<div id="fullBox">' + inpx + '</div>').addClass('showMessage').appendTo('#mainbox');
  });
});
```

```css
#mainbox {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  background: url(../img/dash.png);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #06F;
  z-index: 900;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#bottombox {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  background: url(../img/dash.png);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #06F;
}
.inBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  resize: none;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: -18px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 65px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#fullBox {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.showMessage {
  background-color: #000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainbox"></div>
<div id="bottombox">
  <form>
    <textarea class="inBox"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

And to see the last message, you can use [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to set the vertical position of the scrollbar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var inpx = $('.inBox').val();
    $('.inBox').val("");
    $('<div id="fullBox">' + inpx + '</div>').addClass('showMessage').appendTo('#mainbox');
    $('#mainbox').scrollTop($('#mainbox').height());
  });
});
```

```css
#mainbox {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  background: url(../img/dash.png);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #06F;
  z-index: 900;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#bottombox {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  background: url(../img/dash.png);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #06F;
}
.inBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  resize: none;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: -18px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 65px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#fullBox {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.showMessage {
  background-color: #000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainbox"></div>
<div id="bottombox">
  <form>
    <textarea class="inBox"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a effect to scroll to the bottom of the div, on each click. Just add this code to your `on.("click", function() {` after the `append` function.

```
$('#mainbox').animate({ scrollTop: $("#mainbox").height() }, "fast");
```